# EF 6 not selecting recently updated values unless I rebuild the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2012, I have Project#1 that creates and update entries in a SQL DB using EF 6.

And another Project#2 that is supposed to only select the values created/updated from Project #1

Both projects have a connection string to the local DB

Both projects reference a Data access layer library that contains the .edmx file and the generated models.

- http://localhost:1535/Project1: Should create or edit an entry on
  **Payment** entity
- http://localhost:1896/Project2: Should select values from **Payment**
  entity

The issue is: When I run both applications on different localhost ports I am able to create an entry and select it from the other project

BUT when I want to update an entry I always see the OLD value. And it is only when I rebuild Project #2 in Visual Studio 2012 that I can see the updated value.

Edit action

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix = "paymentform")] PaymentForm paymentform)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Payment payment = db.Payments.Find(paymentform.formId);

        payment.paymenturl = paymentform.paymenturl;

        db.Entry(payment).State = EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(new PaymentConfig());
}
```

What is happening?

Comment: Is object tracking disabled?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, I don't know how do you enable/disable it? Is it set to true by default?

Comment: A very detailed tutorial about change detection can be found here: https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/10/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-1-what-does-detectchanges-do/. Also, you should enable logging to see whether a `UPDATE` SQL statement is executed when you change the payment. If not, then object tracking is most likely disabled: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, I am positive the values are updated because I can see them directly by querying the DB directly right after updating them from the front-end. The problem is with when Project#2 selects the values, I always see old ones. Is object tracking still the issue?

Comment: No, in this case tracking works as you see the changed data in the DB. Please enable logging and check whether a `SELECT` statement is executed when selecting the values onf Project #2 (or use SQL Profiler). Perhaps it's some sort of cache issue.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I logged the queries but I can't see the select, I was suspecting the same thing, it must be a cache issue but even if I clear the cache I don't see the changes. I always have to rebuild

Comment: Do you really have to rebuild or is restarting project #2 also working? I can't immagine why rebuilding would be necessary.

Comment: Open EF context as late as possible and close it as soon as possible. I don't see where you close the context? You should not keep it open.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to avoid using a global variable that initializes the DB context

Here is what I was I doing before in Project#2

```
public class PayController : Controller
{
    Project2Entities db = new Project2Entities();

    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
      //select
    }
   }
```

The solution was to simply use using() with the context inside.

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        using (var context = new Project2Entities())
        {
            //select here
        }
    }
```

I have no idea why declaring the context as a global variable doesn't work properly. If anyone knows please clarify.

Comment: Because you have to close the EF context as soon as possible, you're not supposed to keep it open.

Comment: @L-Four, I use visual studio's default EF template where actions for create/update/delete are already there. The context is global and it uses dispose(), isn't that what it is supposed to do? To close the connection.

Comment: Context should be disposed of as soon as possible, not kept open.